# Emberjs: access application controller from within App.ready

Tags: controller, ember.js, loaded

I want to set a property of ApplicationController from within App.ready. But I don't see how this can be done from within this function

```
App.ready = function() {
    this.controller.set("isLoaded", true) ;
}
```

Is something like this possible ?

CHeers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really possible to set controller values directly if the objects aren't directly linked (Router > Controller > View), but I would also question why you wish to set something in the ApplicationController from the ready event. There are two options that you can take. Either you can create a new Ember object and set a value from the ready event there, and have the controller observe that property (example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/nv7y5/3/). The second option is to respond to the 'didInsertElement' event on the ApplicationView (an example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/nv7y5/1/))

Option 1:

```
App = Em.Application.create({
    ready: function () {
        App.SomeObject.set('someValue', 'A value');
        alert('ready event fired');
    }
});

App.SomeObject = Em.Object.create({
    someValue: '1'
});

App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
    someFunction: function () {
        // do something here (note that the original value of 1 for someValue is never set as the application
        // overwrites it immediately
    }.observes('App.SomeObject.someValue')
});

App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({    
    didInsertElement : function () {
        alert('view has been inserted into the dom');
        alert(App.SomeObject.get('someValue'));
    }
});
```

Option 2:

```
window.App = Em.Application.create({
    ready: function () {
        alert('app is ready');
    }
});

App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend();

App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({    
    didInsertElement : function () {
        alert('view has been inserted into the dom');
    }
});
```

EDIT: Note that I'm pretty sure option 1 is messy and will be frowned upon by the Ember devs (although I can't say for certain).

Comment: thnx a lot! good point! What I need is to delay the rendering process. I want to show my spinner a little bit langer than 0.01s! I can of course render everything inside an element which has **display:none** initially and with your option 1 remove this. Or is there something better ?

Comment: I think if you wanted to delay showing the view, then the cleanest way to do that would be to do a `setTimeout(..., 1000)` on the didInsertElement function of the view. Then after one second or so you can reset the classbinding. I quickly modified this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nv7y5/4/) as an example.

Comment: thnx again, that looks like the way to go!